# FormFlow and suggested action

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I am using FormFlow with enums to render some questions but it seems that formflow is rendering them as a HeroCard with buttons, I'd like the prompts to render as suggested actions so the show as quick replies in FB, what would be the best way of doing this? 
For now, I implemented a custom prompter as follows but like to know if there's a better way of doing this with attributes so I don't need to write custom code.

```
private static async Task<FormPrompt> Prompter(IDialogContext context, FormPrompt prompt, JObject state, IField<JObject> field)
    {
        IMessageActivity promptMessage;

        // Handle buttons as quick replies when possible (FB only renders 11 quick replies)
        if (prompt.Buttons.Count > 0 && prompt.Buttons.Count <= 11)
        {
            // Build a standard prompt with suggested actions. 
            promptMessage = context.MakeMessage();
            promptMessage.Text = prompt.Prompt;
            var actions = prompt.Buttons.Select(button => new CardAction
                {
                    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                    Title = button.Description,
                    Value = button.Description
                })
                .ToList();
            promptMessage.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions(actions: actions);
        }
        else
        {
            promptMessage = await Extensions.GetDefaultPrompter(context, prompt);
        }

        await context.PostAsync(promptMessage);
        return prompt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this functionality than you will have to stick to your implementation. Formflow tries to be as abstract as possible and presenting the enum options as a Herocard with buttons is just a result of that. It does this because almost all channels support Herocards and only facebook supports quick replies.